# Hatcher, degree formula, proposition 2.30, verification

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

He said: "$p_ik_j=0$ for $i\ne j$, as $p_ik_j$ factors through $H_n(U_j,U_j)=0$" (refering to page 136, proof of Proposition 2.30, *Algebraic Topology* by Hatcher, 2022 version).

I want to know: how to factor $p_i k_j$ like that?

Since $p_i$ and $k_j$ are induced by inclusions, I think I shoul factor those inclusion maps (i.e. ordering the spaces pairs) and apply the homology functor. I think this works:

$$ (U_i,U_i\setminus x_i)\to (U_i,U_i) \to (S^n,U_i)\to (S^n,S^n-x_i).$$

I think this is true.

I'm sorry if it is simple or my statement is not clear.

---

**Edit:** (added by Kenny to provide context)

$U_1, U_2, \dots, U_m$ are disjoint open subsets of $S^n$.

For each $i \in \{ 1, \dots, m \}$:

- $x_i$ is a point in $U_i$.
- $k_i$ is the natural homomorphism $$k_i: H_n(U_i, U_i - \{ x_i\}) \to H_n(S^n, S^n - \{ x_1, \dots, x_m \}).$$
- $p_i$ is the natural homomorphism $$p_i : H_n(S^n, S^n - \{ x_1, \dots, x_m \}) \to H_n(S^n, S^n - \{ x_i \} ).$$

The OP wants to prove that $ p_i \circ k_j = 0$ when $i \neq j$.

This proof forms part of Hatcher's proof of the local degree formula for maps $S^n \to S^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the following commutative diagram of maps of pairs.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
(U_j, U_j - \{ x_j \} )  @>>> (S^n, S^n - \{ x_1, \dots, x_m \} ) \\
@VVV @VVV \\
(U_j, U_j) @>>> (S^n, S^n - \{ x_i\}) \end{CD}
Each map of pairs in this diagram is the natural inclusion map between the relevant spaces. Note that it is essential that $i \neq j$. For if $i = j$, then $U_j$ wouldn't be a subset of $S^n - \{ x_i\}$, so it wouldn't make sense to talk about an inclusion map from $U_j$ to $S^n - \{ x_i\}$.

Anyway, these maps of pairs induce homomorphisms on homology groups, giving rise to another commutative diagram.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_n(U_j, U_j - \{ x_j \} )  @>{k_j}>> H_n(S^n, S^n - \{ x_1, \dots, x_m \} ) \\
@VVV @VV{p_i}V \\
H_n(U_j, U_j) @>>> H_n(S^n, S^n - \{ x_i\}) \end{CD}
I've identified the top and right homomorphisms as the $k_j$ and $p_i$ homomorphisms that you're interested in.

$p_i \circ k_j$ is the composition of the top and right homomorphisms. By the commutativity of the diagram, this is the same thing as the composition of the left and bottom homomorphisms. But $H_n(U_j, U_j) = 0$, so the composition of the left and bottom homomorphisms is the zero homomorphism. Therefore, $p_i \circ k_j$ is the zero homomorphism.